# What happens to a table with 2 concurrent updates (SQL)

Tags: sql

What happens to a table in SQL when two update Statements executed at same time from different systems that will overlap on the SQL engine.

Which one will execute first and why?

Comment: There is not first or second. If they affect different rows they are executed simultaneously.

Comment: The question is more "how does sql handle concurrency with concurrent updates". I don't think it should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are never 2 transactions "at the same time" as such
One will always be before or after another.

- If they change the same *row*/same column(s) then one will wait for the other, and overwrite or fail (depending on row-versioning/snapshot mode)
- If they change *different* rows then each is independent of the other

Which one will be first? It depends on which one is scheduled first if they actually arrived at the same instant

Answer (score 0):

The clients don't change the table, they request that the server does that for them. Then it is the job of the server to execute these statements in some order.

What the end result is when they both update the same row, depends on the statement.

- If the where-clause is just `WHERE id=10`, then the last one overwrites the changes of the first one.
- If the where-clause uses something like `WHERE id=10 and theColumn=knownvalue` (where "knownvalue" is the previous value of that column, as far as the client knows), then the first one wins and the last one fails to update anything, because that column was changed.